# How to extract rotation

Tags: java, rotation, itext

I trying to extract rotation of a PDF with TextRenderInfo but i don't know how to calculate.

I read that i can calculate with the baseline but i don't know how

Test method

```
public void test(){

    //Extract all the text of PDF
    ArrayList<InfoText> arrayInfo = extractInfoText(reader, 1);

    //I want to localize a variable that starts with @
    InfoText info = null;

    for (int i=0; i<arrayInfo.size();i++){
        info = arrayInfo.get(i);
        if (info.getInfo().getText().indexOf("@")!=-1){
            break;
        }
    }

    //Know I want to extract de fontsize and the rotation

    //Font size
    float size = renderInfo.getAscentLine().getStartPoint().get(1)- renderInfo.getDescentLine().getStartPoint().get(1);

    //Rotation????
    LineSegment  line = info.getInfo().getBaseline();
    LineSegment  asc = info.getInfo().getAscentLine();
    LineSegment  desc = info.getInfo().getDescentLine();


}
```

Extracting info

```
public static ArrayList<InfoText> extractInfoText(PdfReader reader, int intPage) throws IOException {
  logger.info("UtilesPDF extractText; IN");
  logger.info("UtilesPDF.extractText Page {} ", intPage);
  StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();    
  ArrayList<InfoText> arrayInfo  = new ArrayList<InfoText>();
  RenderListener listener = new PdfTextRenderInfo(out, arrayInfo);
  PdfContentStreamProcessor processor = new PdfContentStreamProcessor(listener);
  PdfDictionary pageDic = reader.getPageN(intPage);
  PdfDictionary resourcesDic = pageDic.getAsDict(PdfName.RESOURCES);

  processor.processContent(ContentByteUtils.getContentBytesForPage(reader, intPage), resourcesDic);      
  logger.info("UtilesPDF.extractText Text Page lenght {} ", out.length());
  logger.info("UtilesPDF.extractText Text Page arrayCharacters size {} ", arrayInfo.size());
  logger.info("UtilesPDF.extractText; OUT");
  return arrayInfo;
}
```

Somebody knows?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It's a geometry problem:

1. The baseline is represented as a `LineSegment`.
2. From that `LineSegment`, you can get the start and end points.
3. Given those two points, you can calculate the slope of the line, using this equation:[image: equation]
4. From the slope of the line, you can calculate the rotation in degrees using this formula:[image: formula]

In the example below, I manually created a `LineSegment` instance. You should use the one you obtain from `info.getInfo().getBaseline()`:

```
LineSegment baseline = new LineSegment(new Vector(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
            new Vector(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f));

Vector startPoint = baseline.getStartPoint();
Vector endPoint = baseline.getEndPoint();

float x1 = startPoint.get(Vector.I1);
float y1 = startPoint.get(Vector.I2);
float x2 = endPoint.get(Vector.I1);
float y2 = endPoint.get(Vector.I2);

float slope = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1);

double rotation = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(slope));

System.out.println(rotation + " degrees"); // prints "45 degrees"
```

Comment: And the obvious warning: Don't divide by zero. `x1 == x2` is not seldom, considering how often page rotation by 90° is used.